# Combine row.Scan and rows.Scan interfaces in go?

Tags: sql, go

I have two queries against a particular table in Go - one to retrieve a single item and the other to return a list. The first one uses `sql.DB.QueryRow` because it only needs to retrieve a single row, and the second one uses `sql.DB.Query` to return a few different results.

The problem is that serialization takes some work and I'd like to DRY it up by having a single method that scans from a database row and reads it into a Go type. My code right now looks like:

```
// Some type which varies considerably from its DB representation, and takes some effort to serialize.
type Foo struct {
    Baz *Baz
    Board [8][8]int
}

// Get one foo by its id
func GetFoo(id int) {
    row := db.QueryRow("select * from foo where id = ?", id)
    // Work that's duplicated from below...
     var foo Foo
    row.Scan(&foo.blah, &foo.etc)
    // Do more work to serialize the type...
}

// Get all of the fooes
func GetFooes() {
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from foo")
    for rows.Next() {
        // Work that's duplicated from above...
        var foo Foo
        rows.Scan(&foo.blah, &foo.etc)
        // Do more work to serialize the type...
    }
}
```

However combining row.Scan and rows.Scan is proving to be a little tricky. I thought I could use something like:

```
func serializeFoo(scanner sql.Scanner) (*Foo, error) {

}
```

though sql.Scanner takes a single `(value interface{})` and not a list of `(...value interface{})`.

Any advice here? Another solution would be to convert the single `QueryRow` call into a `db.Query`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

db.QueryRow is a convenience function. There is no reason to use it unless it will save on typing/code-complexity. In this case, it doesn't so I recommend you just use db.Query.

See http://golang.org/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go?s=25740:25802#L966 for more details

---

As you mentioned, neither Row nor Rows implement the Scanner interface. Scanner is used for arguments of the variatic scan functions.

If you want to have a parameter that allows either Row or Rows, you need to make your own interface For example:

```
func serializeFoo(scanner interface{Scan(dest ...interface{}) error}) (*Foo, error) {

}
```